# Generate Date Range from distinct rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following rows. I need to generate a date range from different rows and same keys.

[image]

And I want the following output:

[image]

Comment: We'd love to help you - just not do it all for you. What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Also ideally don't use images, instead format the data in text.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below logic with the help of CTE and ROW_NUMBER()

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=10bf3c722a85ad3cbc6da14d409ea48d)

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY userid,surveyid ORDER BY date) RN
    FROM your_table
)

SELECT A.userid,A.surveyid,A.date start_date, B.date end_date 
FROM CTE A
LEFT JOIN CTE B ON A.RN = (B.RN-1)
AND A.userid = B.userid 
AND A.surveyid = B.surveyID
WHERE (A.RN%2) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you subtract a sequence of numbers from the `date`, it will be constant when the days are adjacent.  That identifies groups, which can be used for aggregation:

```
select userid, surveyid, min(date), max(date)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by userid, surveyid order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by userid, surveyid,
         dateadd(day, -seqnum, cast(date as date))
```